# How to show all pip / pip3 search results (instead of default limit of 100)?

Tags: python, pip

Pip is giving me limited and inconsistent search results.

When I search for the substring pyqt with `pip3 search pyqt` it doesn't include most of the results I get when I search for the substring pyqt5 with `pip3 search pyqt5`.  Since pyqt is part of the string pyqt5 then pyqt should give me more results than pyqt5.

This is a big problem when searching for a package when you don't know the exact name.  Pyqt is only 1 character off from pyqt5 but pyqt5 is not in the search results for pyqt.

```
In [1]: %paste

import os
pyqt = os.popen('pip3 search pyqt').readlines()
pyqt = [line.split(' ')[0] for line in pyqt if line[0].isalpha()]
pyqt5 = os.popen('pip3 search pyqt5').readlines()
pyqt5 = [line.split(' ')[0] for line in pyqt5 if line[0].isalpha()]
all = os.popen('pip3 search *').readlines()
all = [line.split(' ')[0] for line in all if line[0].isalpha()]
qt5notfound = [line for line in pyqt5 if line not in pyqt]
print(f'A search for pyqt is missing {len(qt5notfound)} results.')
print(f'A search for all packages only gives {len(all)} results.')
## -- End pasted text --

A search for pyqt is missing 64 results.
A search for all packages only gives 99 results.

In [2]:
```

I'm sure there are more than 99 packages in PyPI.  Their website shows 178,863 projects right now.

`pip3 --help` doesn't show any options to increase the number of search results.

Didn't see any limit options in https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/search.py

`grep -Ri limit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/*` points to `utils/ui.py:class RateLimiter` but that is time based.

Is there an option that I'm missing? Or is there another tool that will return ALL packages?

Comment: While less convenient, a [search on PyPI for "pyqt"](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pyqt) yields 402 results, including PyQt5.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a bug report for `pip`, not a question at SO? As for me, I don't use `pip search`, I use search at `pypi.org` because after I found packages I want to view their description, look into VCS repository, and command-line `pip` doesn't allow me all that.